# Check if PDF files are corrupted using command line on Linux

Tags: linux, pdf

I have many PDF files on one folder.

Is it possible check if one or more files are corrupted (zero pages, or unfinished downloads) using the command line, without needing to open them one by one?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can try doing it with `pdfinfo` (here on Fedora in the `poppler-utils` package). `pdfinfo` gets information about the PDF file from its dictionary, so if it finds it the file should be ok

```bash
for f in *.pdf; do
    if ! pdfinfo "$f" &> /dev/null; then
        echo "$f" is broken
    fi
done
```

Comment: I would suggest to replace pdfinfo with pdftotext. This way all text on every page will be checked. And the > gt character should be &> so that all the error messages don't show up.

Comment: All my PDFs are flagged as broken. Hundreds of gigabytes of them. Including ones I just created.  Whether using ``pdfinfo`` or ``pdftotext``...

Comment: What i've found is that pdfinfo reports various types of SyntaxError, and some are tolerated while others are not. For example, files with `Syntax Error: Invalid object stream` can be opened but files with `Syntax Error: Couldn't read xref table` cannot.

Answer (score 24):

My tool of choice for checking PDFs is [`qpdf`](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/). `qpdf` has a `--check` argument that does well to find problems in PDFs.

### Check a single PDF with `qpdf`:

```
qpdf --check test_file.pdf
```

### Check all PDFs in a directory with `qpdf`:

```
find ./directory_to_scan/ -type f -iname '*.pdf' \( -exec sh -c 'qpdf --check "{}" > /dev/null && echo "{}": OK' \; -o -exec echo "{}": FAILED \; \)
```

***Command Explanation:***

- `find ./directory_to_scan/ -type f -iname '*.pdf'`
  Find all files with '.pdf' extension
- `-exec sh -c 'qpdf --check "{}" > /dev/null && echo "{}": OK' \;`
  Execute `qpdf` for each file found and pipe all output to `/dev/null`. Also print filename followed by ': OK' if return status of `qpdf` is 0 (i.e. no errors)
- `-o -exec echo "{}": FAILED \; \)` This gets executed if errors are found: Print filename followed by ": FAILED"

---

### Where to get `qpdf`:

`qpdf` has both Linux and Windows binaries available at: https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf/releases. You could also use your package manager of choice to get it. For example on Ubuntu you can install qpdf using apt with the command:

```
apt install qpdf
```

Comment: However, `qpdf --check` does not detect multiply defined metadata, which are incorrect as they are handle differently by different tools. I've reported a [bug](https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf/issues/345). Other tools such as `pdfinfo` and `pdftk` do not either, but they do not claim to check the PDF structure.

Comment: @vinc17 Has this bug been fixed?

Comment: @user1424739 Yes, this was fixed last year in September, and I could check. For instance, I now get: "WARNING: metadata.pdf (object 16 0, offset 9167): dictionary has duplicated key /Title; last occurrence overrides earlier ones".

Comment: `qpdf --check` has found issues neither `pdfinfo` nor `pdftotext` could find, e.g., "extraneous whitespace seen before xref" after changing the length of the `/CreationDate` field. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/570161.

Comment: `qpdf` gives false positives, way more than true positives.

Comment: a better version (assuming you are not interested in qpdf warnings i.e. exit code 3) with current (Dec 2022) version of qpdf is: `find "./directory_to_scan/" -type f -iname '*.pdf' -exec sh -c 'qpdf --check "{}" >/dev/null 2>&1; [ $? -eq 2 ] && echo "{}"' \;`

Answer (score 18):

```
find . -iname '*.pdf' | while read -r f
  do
    if pdftotext "$f" - &> /dev/null; then 
        echo "$f" was ok;   
    else
        mv "$f" "$f.broken";
        echo "$f" is broken;   
    fi; 
done
```

Comment: To clarify: This script renames the pdf files that are diagnosed as 'broken' by appending .broken to the .pdf extension.

Comment: +1 find is indeed a good tool for the job. to simply list the broken pdf files beneath current directory, this bash find command does it all using a redirection `3>&1 2>/dev/null find . -iname '*.pdf' ! -exec pdfinfo '{}' \; -fprint /dev/fd/3 &>/dev/null`

Answer (score 5):

All of the methods using `pdfinfo` or `pdftotext` have not worked for me. In fact they kept giving me false positives and sometimes created files I didn't need.

What did work was [JHOVE](http://jhove.openpreservation.org/).

**Installation:**

Install the jar from the above link and update your PATH environment variable with this command:

```
echo "export PATH=\$PATH:/REPLACE_WITH/YOUR/PATH_TO/jhove/" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Refresh each terminal with
`source ~/.bash_profile` and you're good to start using it system wide.

**Basic Usage:**

```
jhove -m pdf-hul someFile.pdf
```

You'll get a lot of info about the pdf - more than most people probably need.

**Bash One-Liner:**
Simply returns `valid` or `invalid`:

```
if [[ $(jhove -m pdf-hul someFile.pdf | grep -a "Status:") == *"Well-Formed and valid"* ]]; then echo "valid"; else echo "invalid"; fi;
```

Note that this was run on Mac OS X but I assume it works the same with any Unix based Bash environment.

Answer (score 4):

I got myself an answer:

```
for x in *.pdf; do echo "$x"; pdfinfo "$x" | grep Pages; done
```

PDFs with errors will show errors.

Comment: It is a bad idea (and never really needed) to iterate over the output of `ls`: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: @slhck: This should be handled with `find (1)`. :-)

Comment: @slhck, this loops over a glob, not `ls` output.

Comment: @vonbrand See the initial version here: https://superuser.com/posts/580896/revisions

Answer (score 3):

There are different ways to do this. It depends on what exactly you want to check.

Different commands behave differently, and some exit with status `0` - even if there were some errors.

Also it depends on whether you treat a Warning (possibly also with exit status `0`) as an indication of a corrupt file. And, finally, even if there are some errors/warnings, it depends on what that error/warning is actually about (maybe a corrupt embedded image is not a big problem for you, and you consider such PDF file as valid). There are many things to decide on, and trying different tools may be beneficial.

I have a database of 5031 PDF files, and I have tested them with the following commands:

1. `pdfinfo file.pdf` (~3 min)
2. `pdftotext -layout file.pdf -` (~29 min)
3. `qpdf --check file.pdf` (~222 min)

for the presence of any kind of output to `stderr`, and saved that output to the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UA9HOKW9rYnUOQ5JAnFUwZ7N6YftSotzhe46zBgiEJY/edit?usp=sharing

I filtered the rows by the presence of any output to stderr from ANY command for a file. Every cell contains the full stderr output - double click on it to see the content.

`pdfimages -list file.pdf` - gives exactly same errors as `pdftottext`

So you can test the files with all or selected testing commands the following way:

```
for file in *
do 
    if stderr=$((\
        pdfinfo $file && \
        pdftotext -layout $file - && \
        qpdf --check $file) 2>&1 >/dev/null) && test -z "$stderr"
    then
        echo 'file is ok'
    else
        echo 'file is NOT OK'
    fi
done
```

This script checks both testing commands exit status and **ANY** non-empty output to `stderr`.

It doesn't print out the standard output from the testing commands.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the tools mentioned above, the [pdfcpu](https://github.com/pdfcpu/pdfcpu) library/tool also has PDF validation functionality:

```
pdfcpu validate whatever.pdf
```

Note pdfcpu is still in Alpha at the time of writing (August 2020).

Answer (score 0):

In simple words, **pdf** is an especially structured form of **PostScript**. **qpdf** is probably a good tool to test the structure of the file, but PostScript is a programming language. Checking the syntax of the PostScript part is a good idea, but this is not sufficient. At the run time, many control structures are passed, many functions are called and not all the passed values are always valid. Only at the run time, you will see if all this is running well and if the result is what you want. Further, not all fonts are always included in a pdf file. Missing fonts, which are not available at run time, can cause many problems. The utility **pdffonts** can help you to analyze such problems which can occur here.